Magnetic energy of a dipole,unusual coincidence and alternate derivation?
Here I have done a calculation related to the energy of a dipole in an external uniform magnetic field:
We take a current loop (circular for now) and attach a battery (or any sort of emf device) to it. Now we place our loop in such a way that the magnetic moment $\vec{m}$ is perpendicular to the $\vec{B}$ field. There will be a torque acting on the dipole ($=\vec{m} \times \vec{B}$), so it will tend to rotate the loop. Integrating this torque, $dW=N\,d\theta$, will give the magnetic energy.
Also note that since the loop is rotating, the magnetic flux through it will change, hence producing a back emf. To counter this external work needs to be done by the battery, so that the current in the loop stays constant. We show that the work done is equal to the change in potential energy of the dipole. The magnetic flux is $\Phi_{B}=BA\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle rotated.
So the induced emf is given by
$$\frac{d\Phi_{B}}{dt}=\frac{-BA\sin\theta\, d\theta}{dt} \\
\mathcal{E}=-\frac{d\Phi_{B}}{dt}=\frac{BA\sin\theta\,d\theta}{dt}.$$
The work done by the battery is $dW=-(dq)\,\mathcal{E}=-I\mathcal{E}\,dt=-IBA\sin\theta\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,dt=-IBA\sin\theta\,d(\theta)$. Integrating this expression gives us
$$W=IBA\cos\theta=\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B},$$
which is the exact same formula we get for the potential energy of a dipole in an uniform external field.
Is there any reason why these two should be equal?
PS. Is the derivation which integrates the magnetic torque wrong in the sense that it ignores the work done by battery?Also if the energy is infact due to the external emf source would it be correct to call this the interaction energy of the field and the dipole?

What exactly are you asking?  The magnetic energy of a quasistatic current distribution is always the work done against the back emf produced in the course of assembling the current distribution.

@Buzz If the ring is not stationary, how is the kinetic energy of the ring produced?Is it because of the internal forces in the ring?

Also @Buzz does it mean that the derivation which integrates the torque is wrong?

You only gave one way of calculating the energy in your question.  You didn't mention integrating the torque, which was why I was unsure what you were asking about.  I have edited your question accordingly.  Moreover, if nobody else does first, I will try to write up an answer later today.  What you may be missing is that the work done by the battery is exactly what is needed to keep the current flowing in the loop as it is torqued around, and so it is no coincidence.

You've got the result $-\mathbf m\cdot \mathbf B$ for work of battery because you assumed battery EMF (acting on current in the battery) magnitude is equal, at all times, to magnitude of motional EMF in the circuit due to motion of conductor in magnetic field (and has opposite sign). This is not what usual batteries do; instead, they have roughly constant EMF.

@JánLalinský It can be any emf device, not necessarily a battery. The point is that some external work is being done.

There are three agents really doing work:
(1)The magnetic force.
(2)The emf device to maintain constant current.
(3)The external force such that rotation becomes quasistatic.
(1) can be broken down into two forces during the course of rotation, one along the loop opposing the current and one providing the torque.
The work done by the part of the force opposing the current is cancelled by the extra work done by the emf device to keep the current constant.
In the end the only work done on the system is by the external force.
the work done by external force is what we define as the (change) in potential energy.
This is equal to $-W_{magnetic torque}$.But note that
$$W_{magnetictorque}+W_{magnetic-force-along-ring}=0$$
Also that $$W_{emf}+W_{magnetic-force-along-ring}=0$$
Thus $$W_{magnetictorque}=W_{emf}$$
But according to the previous calculation
$$W_{emf}=\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B}$$
Thus Potential energy of dipole=$-\vec{m}\cdot\vec{B}$.
Which is an alternate derivation,using motional emf.

One way to understand potential energy is exactly as the total amount of work that could be extracted from a system. When we lift a mass to a height $h$ from the ground, for example, it acquire an potential energy $U= mgh$ w.r.t. the ground. If we leave it, this is the amount of work that the gravitational field will realize to bring the mass to the ground.
The situation with the loop is analogous. When you bring it to the field, it is like when we lift the mass: it acquire a potential energy. The work you calculated is the necessary work to bring it again to zero potential energy.
